# How do I get a list of my images from cloudinary from client-side JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, cloudinary

Using the cloudinary API I can get a list of images by `GET`ting the following URL:

```
https://API_KEY:API_SECRET@api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/CLOUD_NAME/resources/image/upload
```

However, using this from client-side JavaScript would expose my account's API key and secret.

It seems like getting a list of images should be possible without exposing my account's credentials.

I've looked at the [Cloudinary AngularJS](https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_angular) client, which has a sample project that implements a slideshow of photos in an account.  From what I can tell, this project uses the following line to get a list of photos in the cloudinary account

```
var url = $.cloudinary.url('myphotoalbum', {format: 'json', type: 'list'});
```

But I can't get this call to return anything.

The [cloudinary JQuery documentation](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/jquery_integration) does not describe the syntax for `$.cloudinary.url()`; the only resource I've found is on the [Cloudinary JQuery Github Page](https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_js), which states that

```
$.cloudinary.url(public_id, options) // Returns a cloudinary URL based on your on your configuration and the given options.
```

What is `public_id`?  What are the `options`?

Comment: If you found any solution please post it here too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36175232/get-list-of-images-from-cloudinary-using-javascript-or-jquery

Answer (score 7):

Browsing through all of your resources indeed require using the secured Admin API. This indeed requires using your `api_secret` which should not be revealed in your client-side code.
However, Cloudinary supports returning a list of all images/raw-files sharing a certain tag. 
The response is a JSON snippet which is automatically updated and cached for 1 hour at the CDN.

The `cloudinary.url` API generates a URL of the specified parameters. So when using:

```
var url = $.cloudinary.url('myphotoalbum', {format: 'json', type: 'list'});
```

this generates a Cloudinary URL, something like the following:

```
http://res.cloudinary.com/<your_cloud_name>/image/list/myphotoalbum.json
```

This URL returns a JSON of all resources in your account sharing the '**myphotoalbum**' tag.

Comment: Can you please give comment/answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36175232/get-list-of-images-from-cloudinary-using-javascript-or-jquery

Comment: @Junaid - Answered

Answer (score 6):

Read documentation link http://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/articles/203189031-How-to-retrieve-a-list-of-all-resources-sharing-the-same-tag-

I did uncheck the 'Resource list' under "Security > Restricted image types". Then I could able to see the image list.

Comment: I have been trying to figure out this issue for a couple of hours, and it was seriously that easy, thank you.