# Get list of images from cloudinary using JavaScript or JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, cloudinary

I have tried every possible code by following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24431943/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-my-images-from-cloudinary-from-client-side-javascript) but code give me following error

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.cloudinary.com/cloud_name/resources/image. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8081' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Code (1)

```
$.get('https://app_key:app_secret@api.cloudinary.com/cloud_name/resources/image');
```

Code (2)

```
$.get('https://api.cloudinary.com/cloud_name/resources/image');
```

For both it fails to authenticate.

**Note:** I am not using any server side programming. Please give me any client side solution/code.

Comment: what you are getting is a CORS error. Try to connect the documentation if you have to send any extra params in the header

Answer (score 0):

By `$.get(...)` I understand that you're performing this call on the client side (jQuery code). This means that you're revealing your account's `api_secret` to your users, they can get your Cloudinary account's credentials with a simply "View source" of your page, then they'll be able to gain full control over your account, including uploading, renaming and even deleting resources. As you probably don't want that to happen, you should either perform this on a server-side only, or use the client-side (unsigned) method of returning all resources sharing a certain tag. For more information:
https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/articles/203189031-How-to-retrieve-a-list-of-all-resources-sharing-the-same-tag-