# List images in Cloudinary account

Tags: cloudinary

I was able to get this link to work: https://API_KEY:API_SECRET@api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/CLOUD_NAME/resources/image/upload But it only shows me the first 10 images, not the entire thing. Any ideas why?

Ref: [How do I get a list of my images from cloudinary from client-side JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24431943/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-my-images-from-cloudinary-from-client-side-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the `max_results` parameter to expend the page size up to 500 resources in a single call. To further list your resources you will need to perform pagination using the `next_cursor` parameter and the attribute that was included on the last resources call.
It will probably look something like:

```
https://API_KEY:API_SECRET@api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/CLOUD_NAME/resources/image/upload?max_results=500
```

and (`<next_cursor_value>` should be extracted from the last returned response):

```
https://API_KEY:API_SECRET@api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/CLOUD_NAME/resources/image/upload?max_results=500&next_cursor=<next_cursor_value>
```

More information is available here (Using Rails syntax):
https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/articles/205714121-How-do-I-browse-through-all-the-resources-in-my-account-using-the-API-

Comment: Nadav, is there a way to use this URL to show only images in a specific folder instead of all?

Comment: @Tyler Sure, you can use `GET /resources/image/upload/?prefix=folder_name` See: http://cloudinary.com/documentation/admin_api#list_all_uploaded_images_with_a_given_prefix

Comment: @NadavOfir , for your last comment, This will list all images inside the folder folder_name including the ones in other subfolders. Is there a way to exclude images in subfolders?

Comment: @javadev I'm afraid this is not supported at the moment. However shouldn't be too difficult to filter based on the response.

Comment: @NadavOfir Thanks.