# Fetch request to Cloudinary API from with React Component fails

Tags: reactjs, http, frontend, cloudinary

I want to make an HTTP request to the Cloudinary API for pictures in my account.  The url necessary looks like this:

`https://<<API KEY>>:<<API SECRET>>@api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/<<RESOURCE NAME>>/resources/image`

and when I hit this url from the browser, I get what I'm looking for, a beautiful JSON object with all my pictures.

But when I hit the url from within a React component,

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.fetchArt();
}
```

I get the following error:

`TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Request 
cannot be constructed from a URL that includes credentials:`

The action creator looks like

```
export function fetchArt() {
  const url = 'https://'+CLOUDINARY_KEY+':'+CLOUDINARY_SECRET+'@api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/prints20/resources/image';
  const request = fetch(url).then(res => res.json())
  return {
    type: FETCH_ART,
    payload: request
  }
}
```

Link to the repo: https://github.com/PantherHawk/prints20-2018

Thanks a million in advance!

Comment: If this is a CLOUDINARY_SECRET, it should be secret. Don't put it in your front-end code. You probably have to create a server that accesses it. It will also fix your CORS problem 

Comment: This should help too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24431943/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-my-images-from-cloudinary-from-client-side-javascript

Answer (score 0):

If your endpoint requires some sort of authorization you'll need to pass that info inside the headers of your request.
Cloudinary Authentication is done using Basic Authentication over secure HTTP. Your Cloudinary API Key and API Secret are used for the authentication.

```
fetch('https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/CLOUD_NAME/resources/image', {
  method: 'get',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + base64.encode(API_KEY + ":" + API_SECRET),
  },
}).then(res => res.json())
```

Comment: The error persists, with the error ```Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.``` Any other tips?

Comment: Should I write this fetch request in my backend server?  Because I'm still finding CORS issues when running it from my componentDidMount function.  Thanks.

Comment: CORS is another issues, this issues is on cloudinary side not in your code. I think cloudinary doesn't allow the origin localhost:8080. Try to deploy your site on server or for security, put in your backend.

Comment: Fetch request only available in browser, if your backend use node js, you can use this library [https://github.com/bitinn/node-fetch](https://github.com/bitinn/node-fetch)